# MongoDB - How to remove an object in an array in case the object contains a value lower than x?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am using Meteor with mongoDB and I need to $pull a whole object out of an array, if the field "removeTime" is lower than a given value.

The document in the collection "items" has this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "Guy1",
    "solvedItems" : {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "itemPush" : "item1-b41f50bc24397735_ABC>14607a25c0864858",
                "actualTime" : 1501281170509.0,
                "removeTime" : 3532817170509.0
            }, 
            {
                "itemPush" : "item2-691aa30080189962_ABC>14607a25c0864858",
                "actualTime" : 1501281255771.0,
                "removeTime" : 1532817255771.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For example the given value is `var givenValue = 2532817255771.0`. So the aim is that the second object in the items-array is beeing removed, but the first one stays in the doc:

```
{
    "_id" : "Guy1",
    "solvedItems" : {
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "itemPush" : "item1-b41f50bc24397735_ABC>14607a25c0864858",
                "actualTime" : 1501281170509.0,
                "removeTime" : 3532817170509.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried many approaches with $elemMatch and $pull, but nothing worked. Here is what I have now:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'pullItem': function () {

//Set the givenValue    
    var givenValue= 2532817255771.0;

//In case there is an element, which is lower than givenValue, execute    
if(items.findOne({'_id': "Guy1", 'solvedItems.items': {$elemMatch: {'removeTime':{$lt:givenValue}}}})) {

items.update({'_id': "Guy1"}, {

  $pull: {
      'solvedItems.items': // Absolutely no idea how to do it
  }
});
      console.log('pulledOut')
} else {
console.log('letItStayInside')}
}});
```

I don´t know how to remove the object containing the lowest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved with basic filter function on an JS array

```
var result = {};
var givenValue = 2532817255771.0;
var tmp = {
"_id" : "Guy1",
"solvedItems" : {
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemPush" : "item1-b41f50bc24397735_ABC>14607a25c0864858",
            "actualTime" : 1501281170509.0,
            "removeTime" : 3532817170509.0
        }, 
        {
            "itemPush" : "item2-691aa30080189962_ABC>14607a25c0864858",
            "actualTime" : 1501281255771.0,
            "removeTime" : 1532817255771.0
        }
    ]
}
}

result = tmp.items.filter(function (element){return element.removeTime < givenValue});
```

Result is the expected array, another property can be re-assigned by yourself, I think it is not the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked fine to get the required object. However, I found this simple solution which worked and pulls directly the matching object: `$pull: {
      'solvedItems.items': {'removeTime':{$lt: givenValue}}`. But I think your solution will work also and is very usefull for further treatment of the data.

Comment: Yes, Mongo has some built-in query to serve this case, but when reading the question, I think to a simple and basic JS solution first.